# Is it possible to modify A VBA code to create a line of data

Tags: excel, vba

I have this VBA function
=CDZE(E4;F4;B4;J1;J2;J3)
It gives me this line :
*0000000000003000345800000845511840000042072023              0

The line contains 62 characters (spaces included until we reach the final zero ‘0’)

The code is :

```
Public Function CDZE(Compte, Cle, montant, NBene, Mois, Annee As String) As String

'Compte
C1 = Len(Compte)
C1 = (18 - C1)
For i = 1 To C1
M = M & "0"
Next
C1 = M & Compte

'Cle
If Cle = "" Then
   Cle = "00"
ElseIf Cle < 10 Then
   Cle = "0" & Cle
Else
   Cle = Cle
End If

'Montant
montant = montant * 100
C2 = Len(montant)
C2 = (13 - C2)
For i = 1 To C2
M1 = M1 & "0"
Next
C2 = M1 & montant

'N Bene
C3 = Len(NBene)
C3 = (7 - C3)
For i = 1 To C3
M2 = M2 & "0"
Next
C3 = M2 & NBene

'Mois
Select Case Mois
Case "JANVIER"
Mois = "01"
Case "FEVRIER"
Mois = "02"
Case "MARS"
Mois = "03"
Case "AVRIL"
Mois = "04"
Case "MAI"
Mois = "05"
Case "JUIN"
Mois = "06"
Case "JUILLET"
Mois = "07"
Case "AOUT"
Mois = "08"
Case "SEPTEMBRE"
Mois = "09"
Case "OCTOBRE"
Mois = "10"
Case "NOVEMBRE"
Mois = "11"
Case "DECEMBRE"
Mois = "12"
End Select

'Annee
C4 = "*" & C1 & Cle & C2 & C3 & Mois & Annee
    
'CD ZERO
C5 = Len(C4)
C5 = (61 - C5)
For i = 1 To C5
M3 = M3 & " "
Next
C5 = C4 & M3

CDZE = C5 & "0"

End Function
```

There always a star (*) at the beginning of the line.
From position 2 to position 21 we have the accountof 20 characters.
From position 22 to position 34 we have a sum of a range, example : let’s assume the range from G2 and down contains 10000.00, 20000.00, 300000.00, the sum would be 330000.00
So in the line that is created by the code it would appear in the position from posion 27 to position 34 :
*0000000000003000345800000330000000000042072023              0
If the sum for example 99999999999.99, the line would be
*0000000000003000345899999999999990000042072023              0
From position 35 to 41 we have the number of line that the range that contains the amounts have.
The line contain the number 42, so there are 42 lines, if the line for example contains 8888888, it means the line will look line :
*0000000000003000345899999999999998888888072023              0
From position 42 to 43 we have the month numth : 07 for july, 08 for august etc.
Then we have the year from position 44 to 47 : 2023, 2024 and so on.
Fro position 48 to 61 we have spaces. And the have the zero ‘0’ at the end of the line.

I would like to modify it so that :

1. The star (*) appears automatically.
2. the account on 20 characters appears automatically which is always : 00799999000030003458. (edited on comment)
3. the sum of lines contained in the range ‘G2 and down’ appears automatically in position 22 to 34.
4. the number of lines contained in the range ‘G2 and down’ appears automatically in position 35 to 41.
5. the number corresponding to the month we are in appears automatically in position 42 to 43, 07 for july, 08 for august… etc.
6. the number corresponding to the year we are in appears automatically in position 44 to 47, 2023, 2024… etc.
7. 14 spaces frop position 48 to 61
8. and finally the zero ‘0’ and the end of the line.

So I want to just create a button assigned to it a vba code, that by just clicking on it the above data will be dumped to the cell ‘H1’

Comment: I am afraid I cannot understand what you want... Do you want processing the resulted line (you show )? Do you want adapting the function to return something else? If the second case, I am afraid that your approach, describing what the return of a not useful function means, is not the most appropriate. I would suggest you to show us the data where from the function takes data (parameters: E4;F4;B4;J1;J2;J3) and explain what you want from the new function to return. Based on what logic to process them in the way you need?

Comment: FaneDuru
« E4 » and « F4 » is the account number that i have put in position 2 to 21 : 00799999000030003458
« B5 » is the sum of amounts contained in the range from G2 and down.
« J1 » is the number of lines contained in the range from G2 and down.
« J2 » is the number corresponding to the month, eg 07 for july.
« J3 » is the number corresponding to the year, eg 2023.

Comment: You said "H1 to H3 contains 10000.00, 20000.00, 300000.00" but you want the result "dumped to the cell ‘H1’ " ? This will overwrite one of the inputs.

Comment: Also 0079999000030003458 is only 19 characters

Comment: CDP1802
Sorry, there was an error, I should say G1 G2 G3…. And so forth Instead of
H1 to H3 contains 10000.00, 20000.00, 300000.00"
And also 00799999000030003458 instead of 0079999000030003458

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try this. If adequate delete the comment lines in it. (Beginning with `'` )

```
Public Sub CDZE() '(Compte, Cle, montant, NBene, Mois, Annee As String) As String

'Compte
'C1 = Len(Compte)
'C1 = (18 - C1)
'For i = 1 To C1
'M = M & "0"
'Next
'C1 = M & Compte
C1 = "00799999000030003458"
'Cle
'If Cle = "" Then
'   Cle = "00"
'ElseIf Cle < 10 Then
'   Cle = "0" & Cle
'Else
'   Cle = Cle
'End If
LineCount = Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
Cle = WorksheetFunction.Sum(ActiveSheet.Range("G2:G" & LineCount))
Cle = CStr(Format(Cle * 100, "0000000000000"))
'Montant
'montant = montant * 100
'C2 = Len(montant)
'C2 = (13 - C2)
'For i = 1 To C2
'M1 = M1 & "0"
'Next
'C2 = M1 & montant
C2 = CStr(Format(LineCount - 1, "0000000"))
Mois = Format(Month(Now), "00") & Year(Now)
'N Bene
'C3 = Len(NBene)
'C3 = (7 - C3)
'1 For i = 1 To C3
'M2 = M2 & "0"
'Next
'C3 = M2 & NBene
C3 = Space(14) & "0"
'Mois
'Select Case Mois
'Case "JANVIER"
'Mois = "01"
'Case "FEVRIER"
'Mois = "02"
'Case "MARS"
'Mois = "03"
'Case "AVRIL"
'Mois = "04"
'Case "MAI"
'Mois = "05"
'Case "JUIN"
'Mois = "06"
'Case "JUILLET"
'Mois = "07"
'Case "AOUT"
'Mois = "08"
'Case "SEPTEMBRE"
'Mois = "09"
'Case "OCTOBRE"
'Mois = "10"
'Case "NOVEMBRE"
'Mois = "11"
'Case "DECEMBRE"
'Mois = "12"
'End Select

'Annee
C4 = "*" & C1 & Cle & C2 & Mois & C3
    
'CD ZERO
'C5 = Len(C4)
'C5 = (61 - C5)
'For i = 1 To C5
'M3 = M3 & " "
'Next
'C5 = C4 & M3
ActiveSheet.Range("H1") = C4
'CDZE = C5 & "0"

End Sub
```

**This is the Function formatted code**

```
'Compte is the account number max. 20 characters, if less leading 0 added,
'if longer last 20 characters used.
'Begin Compte value with an `'`, otherwise it is a number and will be rounded,
'or explicitly define cell Number Format as Text.
'Cle is the range to sum without header in range format.
'Mois and Annee are numbers, if not assigned the actual (today) value is used.
'Mois and Annee numbers are converted to 2 and 4 charactes long with leading zeros.
'Longer values leave last positions.




Public Function CDZEman(Compte As String, Cle As Range, Optional mois As String, Optional annee As String) As String


C1 = Right("00000000000000000000" & Compte, 20)
Set CleRange = Cle
cler = WorksheetFunction.Sum(CleRange)
cler = CStr(Format(cler * 100, "0000000000000"))
C2 = CStr(Format(Cle.Rows.Count, "0000000"))
If mois = "" Then mois = Month(Now())
If annee = "" Then annee = Year(Now())

mois = Right(CStr(Format(mois, "00")), 2) & Right(CStr(Format(annee, "0000")), 4)
C3 = Space(14) & "0"

CDZEman = "*" & C1 & cler & C2 & mois & C3


End Function
```

Comment: First time it was only 61 character long, but noticed the comment.

Comment: Black cat: sorry for asking again, could you change your solution to a 'public function', keeping the same logic, but letting the function to give me the possibility of entering manually the Number account, the range containing the amounts to be added, the numbers of lines containing the amounts, the month and the year. For exemple: public function header(account, amount range, lines range, month, year)

Comment: @snol I added the Function variant. Lines range is the rows count of the amount range as given in Item 4.

Comment: i'm very gratefull Black cat, but please on final request, when I select the WHOLE range where the amount are (  C2 = CStr(Format(Cle.Rows.Count, "0000000"))  ), let's say G:G, i get 1048576 which is the number of lines in excel, I want to the get the number of lines containing the amounts in numbers. for example rows 2,3,4,5 contain amounts, 6 and down are empty, row 1 contains the name of the column, so in the end i want to get 4 ((  C2 = CStr(Format(Cle.Rows.Count, "0000004"))